# How to find all keys in map in C++11 which are equal or higher than KEY_1 and lower than KEY_2?

Tags: c++, c++11

How do I find all keys in map in C++11 which are equal or higher than KEY_1 and lower than KEY_2?

I usually program in Java and don't have much experience in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza Integers are keys and I need to find all in range [Key_one, Key_two)

Comment: @PaolaJ. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
auto minmax = std::minmax( KEY_1, KEY_2, m.key_comp() );

auto first = m.lower_bound( minmax.first );
auto last  = m.upper_bound( minmax.second );
```

Here is a demonstrative program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::map<int, int> m = 
    { 
        { 1, 10 }, { 2, 20 }, { 3, 30 }, {4, 40 }, { 5, 50 }, { 6, 60 }, { 7, 70 }
    };

    int key1 = 5;
    int key2 = 3;

    auto minmax = std::minmax( key1, key2, m.key_comp() );

    auto first = m.lower_bound( minmax.first );
    auto last = m.upper_bound( minmax.second );

    for ( auto current = first; current != last; ++current )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << current->first
                  << ", " << current->second
                  << " }" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
{ 3, 30 }
{ 4, 40 }
{ 5, 50 }
```

Or a more interesting example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main() 
{
    std::map<int, int> m1 = 
    { 
        { 1, 10 }, { 2, 20 }, { 3, 30 }, { 4, 40 }, { 5, 50 }, { 6, 60 }, { 7, 70 }
    };

    int key1 = 5;
    int key2 = 3;

    auto minmax1 = std::minmax( key1, key2, m1.key_comp() );

    auto first1 = m1.lower_bound( minmax1.first );
    auto last1  = m1.upper_bound( minmax1.second );

    for ( auto current = first1; current != last1; ++current )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << current->first
                  << ", " << current->second
                  << " }" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::map<int, int, std::greater<int>> m2 = 
    { 
        { 1, 10 }, { 2, 20 }, { 3, 30 }, { 4, 40 }, { 5, 50 }, { 6, 60 }, { 7, 70 }
    };

    auto minmax2 = std::minmax( key1, key2, m2.key_comp() );

    auto first2 = m2.lower_bound( minmax2.first );
    auto last2  = m2.upper_bound( minmax2.second );

    for ( auto current = first2; current != last2; ++current )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << current->first
                  << ", " << current->second
                  << " }" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
{ 3, 30 }
{ 4, 40 }
{ 5, 50 }

{ 5, 50 }
{ 4, 40 }
{ 3, 30 }
```

If you want to exclude the upper bound from the range then you have to substitute the call of method `upper_bound` to `lower_bound` that is the code will contain two calls of `lower_bound` with corresponding keys. For example

```
auto first1 = m1.lower_bound( minmax1.first );
auto last1  = m1.lower_bound( minmax1.second );
```

If you want to exclude lower bound from the range then you can write

```
auto first1 = m1.upper_bound( minmax1.first );
auto last1  = m1.upper_bound( minmax1.second );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [*`std::map::lower_bound`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound)

```
// All elements in [KEY1 KEY2 )
auto it1 = m.lower_bound ( KEY_1  ) ;
auto it2 = m.lower_bound(  KEY_2  ) ;

for( auto it = it1 ; it != it2 ; ++it )
{
   // it->first , it->second
}
```

Comment: Demo [_Here_](http://rextester.com/WSHH37077)

Comment: Your demo correctly uses `lower_bound` twice. You should do the same thing in your answer. :)

Comment: @hvd yeah, I forgot to update, thanks